# Spring MVC request mapping - full request URI

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, web-applications

When creating or listing and item using REST api I return also the whole resource path.

For example creating a person record returns `http://service:9000/person/1234`in response. In order to get schema, host & port part like  `http://service:9000`, I extract it from  URL obtained by `HttpServletRequest.getRequestURL()`.

Example (not the production code but conceptually same):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Object putPerson(
        @RequestParam(value = "name") String name,
            HttpServletRequest req) {

      long id = createPerson(name);
      String uriStart = RestUtils.getSchemeHostPortUrlPart(req
            .getRequestURL().toString());
      String uri = uriStart + "/person/" + id;
      Person person = new Person(name, id, uri);

      return person; //Serialized to json by Spring & Jackson
}

//Simple bean-like class
public class Person {  
//Getter methods for uri, name & id
}
```

Since this is quite a boiler plate code which repeats in every method I was wondering if Spring does not have support for this which eluded me when reading it's documentation.

By this I mean accessing either URL without neededn `HttpServletRequest` or even better its schema, host, port part only.

Comment: Can you update to show what you are doing with the URL?

Comment: If it is for serious work, **BEWARE** : in real world application servers are often hidden for security reasons behind reverse proxies : the host-port known by the application server is **not** the one used by a user. Reverse proxies do their best to cope with that but caveat emptor ...

Answer (score 4):

The documentation provides a lot of [examples](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-uri-building) for constructing URIs using a `UriComponentsBuilder`.

Furthermore I recommend to take a look at [Spring HATEOAS](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hateoas/) if you want to take your REST API to the next level.

BTW: PUT means that you place what you send (request body) to the location to which you send it (URL). If nothing is there something new is created, otherwise what exists is updated (replaced).

This is not what is happening in your example. The proper way would be to either POST to `/person` or PUT to the person's own URL, e.g. `/person/1234`, provided you have the ID beforehand.

Comment: PUT can also be used for creation, according to the spec. An analogy would be Map's put, which creates or replaces an entry. Although the code in OP states `createPerson` only.

Comment: @iwat0qs It says so in the answer: _You can either POST to /person or PUT to the person's own URI, e.g. /person/1234_

Comment: Ah, okay. Maybe I misunderstood. 
I've read "replace" as in "replace what already exists", and "PUT to the person's own URI" as in "PUT into the URI of a person that already exists". 

E.g. MDN puts it this way, to avoid ambiguity: "The HTTP PUT request method creates a new resource or replaces a representation of the target resource with the request payload.". I haven't downvoted or anything, it's just a minor clarification to your answer. 

Because otherwise one can understand, that PUT only replaces something that already exists, and returns 404 otherwise, for example

Comment: @iwat0qs Your 404 example offers an interesting aspect. I have updated my answer to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 2):

You can construct the URI in an interceptor (that's executed previous to controller methods) and put it as an attribute and use it in the controller method.

Comment: Can you provide some links with examples of interceptors or keywords to look for?

Comment: Example of interceptor: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handler-interceptors-example/

An interceptor is a class with two methods preHandle and postHandle and you can use it to intercept the request an add headers, retrieve url or uri... whatever you want. It's executed prior to controller methods in cascade (you could use more than one)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is quite simple. Look at this example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public Object putPerson(@RequestParam(value = "name") String name, HttpServletRequest req) {

  long id = createPerson(name);
  Person person = new Person(id, name, req);

  return person; //Serialized to json by Spring & Jackson
}

public class JsonResponse {

    private String url;

    public JsonResponse(HttpServletRequest request) {
        url = request.getRequestURI() + "?" + request.getQueryString();
    }

    public final String url() {
        return url;
    }
}

public class User extends JsonResponse {

    private Long   id;
    private String name;

    public User(Long id, String name, HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    // Getter, Setter

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder` like this:

```
String uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest()
    .replacePath("/person/{id}")
    .buildAndExpand(id)
    .toUriString();
```